# R package not compatible with 3.5.3

Tags: r, package

I am attempting to install a package that was made on my computer, but I am having issues. Installing seemed to work fine, but I got a warning:

> Warning in install.packages :
>   package ‘abcmlr’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3)

This naturally throws the error when calling `library`

> Error in library(abcmlr) : 'abcmlr' Not a valid package that has already been installed

Using `.libPaths()` returns `"C:/Users/amlut/Documents/R/win-library/3.5" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.3/library"`. So I presume this is why `library()` is giving me an error.

Why does installing my package not work for version 3.5.3 (Does this question require additional information about my package)? Is it possible to make my package work for 3.5.3? What steps would be required to achieve this?

Thank you.

Edit: this is a package I made, and I am using devtools::install

DESCRIPTION:

```
Package: abcmlr
Type: Package
Title: Analysis of Bone Counts by Maximum Likelihood
Version: 0.1.0
Author: 
Maintainer: 
Description: See Rogers ABCML for details
License:  
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
NeedsCompilation: no
Packaged: 2019-06-14 21:17:42 UTC; amlut
Built: R 3.5.3; ; 2019-06-14 21:17:43 UTC; windows
```

Output from `devtools::install`:

```
devtools::install("C:/Users/amlut/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/abcmlr")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but the version of Rtools previously installed in C:/Rtools has been deleted.

Please download and install Rtools 3.5 from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\amlut\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\abcmlr/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'abcmlr':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Removed empty directory 'abcmlr/man'
-  building 'abcmlr_0.1.0.tar.gz'

Running "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" INSTALL "C:\Users\amlut\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGySaDj/abcmlr_0.1.0.tar.gz" --install-tests 
* installing to library 'C:/Users/amlut/Documents/R/win-library/3.5'
* installing *source* package 'abcmlr' ...
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
No man pages found in package ** help
 'abcmlr' 
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
* DONE (abcmlr)
In R CMD INSTALL

library(abcmlr)
```

Comment: I do not see this package listed on CRAN.  Where does it come from?

Comment: It is one I made, and I attempting to install it.

Comment: Can you show exactly what code you are running. You say you are using `devtools::install` but that error message looks like you are using `install.packages()`. Are you currently running R 3.5.3? Is that what you used to make the package?

Comment: How are you attempting to install it? If you try `install.packages("abcmlr")`, then it *will always fail*, since the package is not available on CRAN or your list of repositories. If instead you do `install.packages("/path/to/abcmlr-1.0.0.tar.gz")`, it should install it just fine.

Comment: You are right, I attempted to use `install.packages` first because `install` didn't work. I mixed up the errors. The error `install` gave was `devtools::install("abcmlr")`
`Error: Can't find 'C:\Users\amlut\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\abcmlr\abcmlr'.` The version I am using is 3.5.3, and I made the package in 3.5.3 as well. I copied the package into 3.4 to see if `install` would work, but still gave the same error.

Comment: (That last command works if you do `devtools::build(...)` which produces a `.tar.gz` file.)

Comment: I recommend giving the full absolute path to `devtools::install` in this instance, since it looks like your current working directory is `c:/..../win-library/3.4/abcmlr` ... which makes no sense to me. Do you normally set your current working directory to an R repository? I'd think that that's a bad idea in many ways. (`devtools` functions typically prepend the argument to the current dir, ergo your `.../3.4/abcmlr/abcmlr` problem.)

Comment: @r2evans I attempted that, but it still says it is not compatible with 3.5.3. My current working directory should be my Documents folder, unless I messed something up.

Comment: It is difficult to solve that error from `devtools::build` without more information about the package. Is it available in a github repo? If not, can you add the contents of `DESCRIPTION` to your question? Perhaps there's a clue in there.

Comment: `DESCRIPTION` says the version is `0.1.0`. Is this causing the mishap? Edit: Specifying the absolute path seemed to fix it

Comment: The `Version:` component of `DESCRIPTION` is for your package only, and has no impact on anything else. What might be interesting is the rest of it, namely (I wonder) if something else you're depending on has limitations that you inherit. Please add the contents of `DESCRIPTION` to your question.

Comment: @r2evans added.

Comment: That's somewhat informative. Is it true that your package relies solely on base packages/functions? No external packages at all? Okay, c'est bien. Next step, can you post the output from `devtools::install("/path/to/abcmlr")`? (I'm intentionally using an absolute path, per a previous comment about relative-vs-absolute paths.)

Comment: @r2evans sorry late response, added.

Comment: No worries, the delay goes back on you ;-). I think the first few lines are a good start: *"Please download and install Rtools 3.5 from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/."* While I don't know that Rtools is the problem here, the fact that `devtools` complaining about it is something I'm not qualified to currently ignore. Are you able to download/install Rtools-3.5?

Comment: I believe that was the issue. Thank you!